# Opis\Closure\SerializableClosure - Error afer PHP 8.1 Update

Tags: laravel-8

I have updated my system to **PHP 8.1** (XAMPP).
Now I have the problem that when I enter the command "**php artisan serve**" I get the following error message:

```
Opis\Closure\SerializableClosure implements the Serializable interface, which is deprecated.
 Implement __serialize() and __unserialize() instead 
(or in addition, if support for old PHP versions is necessary).
```

Can you help me what I can do to make it work again?

Comment: That isn't (or shouldn't be) a fatal error, just advance notice that something _will_ be removed in a future version.

Comment: But now I have the problem that the software can no longer be started and this error always occurs, no matter what php artisan command I enter...

Answer (score 16):

You need to update laravel dependencies. Simply go to your project root directory and use composer to update dependencies using command prompt.

Command should be:

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

`composer upgrade laravel/framework --with-all-dependencies`

You would need to update `laravel/framework` *with* it's dependencies. Instead of running `composer upgrade` which upgrades all packages, you could just run `composer upgrade laravel/framework --with-all-dependencies`, shorthand is `-W`.

From the composer command help `-W Update also dependencies of packages in the argument list, including those which are root requirements.`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with my version of laravel (8.54) after updating my PHP version to version 8.1
So what I did is to downgrade my PHP version to version 8.0.
Then it worked again.
PS: make sure to have `framework/sessions`, `framework/views` and `framework/cache` in the `storage` folder

Answer (score 0):

Error: C:\laragon\www\Laravel\brainiark_shop\vendor\opis\closure\src\SerializableClosure.php on line 18

I have the issue recently and it is caused by the Serializable interface not being use anymore in latest version of PHP.

You will find this on line 18 in this location on your project:
vendor/opis/closure/src/SerializableCourse.php:

First Step (1):
class SerializableClosure implements Serializable {}

change it to:
class SerializableClosure {}

Second Step (2):
public function serialize() {}

change it to:
public function __serialize() {}

Third Step (3):
public function serialize() {}

change it to:
public function __serialize() {}

That's all, don't bother to thank me (smile)

Comment: Changing files in the `vendor/`-folder is very much not recommended as you will lose them next time you run `composer update`

Answer (score -1):

Just delete `composer.lock.json`, with me resolve and after run `composer install`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).